# Multilingualism in already completed project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization, multilingual

I'm working on a project which is in very advanced stage of development. We have new customers which want multilingualism. The project is huge and we have to place all strings in the code files into Resources.aspx files. It's easy to see that it's cumbersome to go and check each file in the project by hand for text strings and placing them manually in the resources. Does exists some tips or tools for this kind of situation ?

Comment: Charge them for the late feature addition, hire people to do the tedious work for you.

Comment: I'm asking for some sort of automation of the process. They're charged already :)

Comment: A more flexible approach is to use Rick Strahl's DB driven approach - it wont do the tedious work for you but might work out better in the long run http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/wwdbresourceprovider/ I agree with @RyanMcDonough though charge the client more and hire cheap resources to do the manual part for you

Comment: There's not much in the way of automation for this, given the size of the project you've suggested automation could quite easily include or exclude items you need/don't need referencing.

Comment: @DTs charging them and then getting a free website to do most of the work for you, very devious ;)

Comment: what do you mean by free website ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this tool: http://www.jollans.com/tiki2/tiki-index.php?page=MultiLangVsNet&bl=y

Some highlights:

"The Add-In scans your project, looking for strings defined in properties of controls and program source code"

"In both cases, you can
select the texts which you wish to translate
hide texts which you do not wish to translate
Note
Most programs contain a lot of text strings which do not require translation. In many cases, translating a string will actually cause a program error. Selecting the texts which require translation is a job which can only be performed by the programmer.

The Multi-Language Add-In makes it easy to start this job late in project development."

"The Add-In shows you a list of all languages supported by Windows. Simply select a language from the list to add it to the project.

For each language, an additional column is added to the grids, showing the strings for this language."

"Enter translations with Microsoft Excel or OpenOffice"

Supports VS2002 to VS2012 (the info-page says 2010, but the download says 2012) !

It's not free though... But it's not that expensive.

Comment: It's good, though one of the check is that the control has Localizable as an attribute, same effort to go through all the controls and add that as an option. Upvote though for this.

Comment: You could probably write a small app to go and add that property/attribute in the relevant source files, no?

Comment: You probably could yeah, though since they are asking this question maybe they can't heh. I might look at this for a future project though.